# Micropython ESP8266 Error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute (works fine in Python)

Tags: python, esp8266, micropython

I am coding with Thonny on a ESP8266 NodeMCU with Micropython.
I managed to flash chip with Micropython, connect, add an OLED display and run my first Hello World script.
However, when I use some of my previously tried and tested Python Code, I get a **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute xyz** Error. From all I understand this shouldnt be a MicroPython vs python issue, so I am a bit lost.

Here is my main.py that throws the error:

```py
from machine import Pin, I2C
import ssd1306
from time import sleep
import tubestatus


# ESP8266 Pin assignment
i2c = I2C(-1, scl=Pin(5), sda=Pin(4))

oled_width = 128
oled_height = 64
oled = ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(oled_width, oled_height, i2c)

while True:
    # Create a new status object for retrieving data
    current_status = tubestatus.Status()

    # Get a list of tube lines
    lines = current_status.list_lines()

    for line in lines:
        oled.text(line, 0, 0)
        oled.text(current_status.get_status(line).description, 0, 10)
        oled.show()
        time.sleep(3)
```

The `import tubestatus` refers to [this](https://github.com/jacobtomlinson/tube-status/tree/master/tubestatus) super simple (but working) github module which is available on the ESP8266 (and I assume is found by the main.py as it seems to refer to a missing attribute in the module).

Any pointers are most welcome!
Thank you

[This shows the files on the device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lOkT.png)

Comment: Share full error trace please

Comment: When you say "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute xyz", presumably it didn't say `xyz` - what was the exact failure? Or ideally, as Kacper requested, the full error trace

Comment: Hi, thank you @KacperFloriański - here is what I get on the shell (I am not sure if that's the full error trace you suggest I share, if not please advise): 

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Status'

MicroPython v1.12 on 2019-12-20; ESP module with ESP8266
Type "help()" for more information.```

Comment: It seems `Status` is somehow missing from your `tubestatus` installation - are you sure the package is installed correctly? You can verify it's not there if `print("Status" in tubestatus.__dict__)` prints `False` - or just print the entire `__dict__` and see what's inside. I don't know where the files are placed on your machine but verifying that `Status.py` is somewhere would be a good start.

Comment: Thanks...the Status.py file are in the tubestatus folder. Take a look here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lOkT.png - but the 
```print("Status" in tubestatus.__dict__)```
gives me an undefined....This looks like a stupid beginners mistake?

Comment: Here is what I get....or better, I dont get it:
```import tubestatus
>>> tubestatus.__dict__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__dict__'```

Comment: According to https://github.com/micropython/micropython/wiki/Differences, it seems that `Instance __dict__ support is optional (disabled in many ports) and read-only, so foo.__dict__['bar'] = 23 or foo.__dict__.update({'bar': 23}) does not work.`. Unfortunately, I haven't used micropython before so I can't provide any further help, sorry.